# update migration for all tenant in abp boilerplate

Tags: migration

How to make it so that when adding a new migration, tenants that do not share the same database automatically update according to the host when they publish the application to IIS

I want when I add migration on the host, can the tenant's database also update that migration? with the application published to IIS